Dynamically determine xarray chunk size by computational resources?
I've been brainstorming ways to dynamically determine an optimal chunk size for an xarray based on the computational resources available in a given machine. This machine is unknown; it could be anything from a laptop to a high-performance computer. The size of the xarray is also an unknown; it could be small, it could be very large. My idea is to start with the smallest possible chunk size, run a user-defined function on this chunk whilst monitoring RAM usage and the time it takes to complete. If it succeeds with no issues, then try again with the same user-defined function but increase to a larger chunk size. I want to repeat this until a find a "sweet-spot" where I'm optimizing for run time and RAM usage. I'm planning to use Docker containers to determine this chunk size so as to not accidentally crash my main program. The main program should be able to get this optimal chunk size from the Docker tests and use it later to do a full-fledged run of the user-defined function in parallel. Is there a solution for determining chunk size by resources that already exists? Maybe something with Dask that I am not familiar with?
